# Let $A$ be the sum of the digits of $4444^{4444}$ and $B$ the sum of the digits of $A$ . Find the sum of the digits of $B$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $A$ be the sum of the digits of $4444^{4444}$ and $B$ the sum of the digits of $A$ . Find the sum of the digits of $B$.

The solution given in the book is as follows:

> Since $4444^{4444}<10^{4444}$ it is easy to see that $A<44440$ . Therefore, $B<5.9=45$ which implies that the sum of digits is a one digit number . We also know that $A$ and $B$ (and the sum of its digits as well) are congruent to $4444^{4444}$ modulo 9 . That is, they all have remainder $7$ when divided by $9$. Thus the sum of digits of $B$ must be $7$.

However, I am not getting the idea of the solution...i mean how do they conclude "Since $4444^{4444}<10^{4444}$ it is easy to see that $A<44440$ ." Is it at all true as $10<4444$ and $ 4444^{4444}<10^{4444}$...Also, how does they conclude that "Therefore, $B<5.9=45$ which implies that the sum of digits is a one digit number ." I mean how do they say that sum of digits of $B$ is a one digit number?...I am not quite getting the idea of the solution.....

Comment: That is a well-known problem from IMO 1975. This question was discussed many times here.

Comment: @lulu Actually I am not quite getting the idea...

Comment: Try to ask a more precise question.  You've been handed multiple solutions....what exactly don't you understand?

Comment: The $.$ in $B<5.9=45$ is a multiplication.  You could also say that  if $A< 44440$ then the sum of digits of $A$ is less than $9+9+9+9+9$ since each digit is nine or smaller and the first is four or smaller

Comment: @lulu Well, the link u posted has the sum of digits of $A$ as $B$  and sum of digits of $B$ as $C$ and sum of digits of $C$ as $D$ and it calculates $D$.... but here the question asks to find $C$...how to do that?...

Comment: Well, try.  Note however that something seems off, as $4444^{4444}$ is obviously not less than $10^{4444}$.  In any event, [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/1975_IMO_Problems/Problem_4) is another solution.

Comment: @lulu the solution link u posted also has something bit off about it ...i mean they say that $4444^{4444}<10000^{4444}=10^{4.4444}$ ...So, $4444^{4444}$ has less than $17776$  digits so, it has maximum sum of digits of $9.17775=159975$ ...But then it says $A$ becomes maximum if in $4444$ it was $9999$...so it says $B\leq 45$...how does they draw the conclusion?

Comment: No, they are correct.  Since $A<159975$ the maximum sum of digits occurs for $A=99999$.  Putting the $1$ in on the left is no good since it forces the second digit to be $≤5$.  Thus you gain $1$ in the sum but lose at least $4$.

Comment: @lulu Thanks a lot! i get it now....